# Angular 5 build and Zone.js

Tags: django, python-3.x, angular-cli, angular5

Have the picture error after build my angular 5 app, i serve my app with a django view.

I added the zone.js dependencie in my angular package.json file but i get the same error.

[image: errorimage]

this is my Github gists [view and template](https://gist.github.com/Gytree/7dcf192e64f64864468d3af682d881fd), the view load all files in the static path. this works fine.

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solve, the error it's the order of the scripts load by my django view, the view load the scripts in the folders order, but most be the next:

- inline
- polyfills
- scripts
- main